Is the right instrument classification for the voice “multitimbral monophonic”?
I was looking up the word for an instrument that can only produce one timbre and the word I found was monotimbral. Wikipedia also had a slightly strange answer for both mono and multi. It says multitimbral means it could produce multiple timbres simultaneously, but that’s basically the definition for polyphonic.
The way I understand it regardless of what the wikipedia says is, monotimbral is an instrument that can only produce one timbre and multitimbral is an instrument that can produce multiple timbres. Then multitimbral monophonic would mean it can produce multiple timbres but only one at a time. Is this correct or am I missing something?

This might be complicated by the fact that some synthesizers are described as being "multitimbral" when they can play two or more sounds at the same time. A typical synthesizer is capable of a variety of timbres (AKA "patches") but only one timbre at a time. Some synths can have two or more separate patches playing either using split points or layering or even a combination. Normally "monophonic" means one note at a time, not one timbre at a time.

“that’s basically the definition for polyphonic” — not really.  A polyphonic instrument would be able to play two or more notes simultaneously, but they might all have the same character (e.g. sounding like two or more trumpets).  Whereas if it were multitimbral it would also be able to play notes with different characters simultaneously (e.g. sounding like a trumpet and a harp).

@gidds gotcha. But so then what would we call the voice then? Because it can produce multiple timbres but its not polyphonic.

@Lecifer That part of your question is interesting…  :-)  I can't think of a clear term for it.  It's not what the term ‘multitimbral’ was intended for (which, as Todd said, was synths and synth modules).  Also, the range of different sounds is fairly limited — nearly all would be clearly identifiable as a voice.  If you have a specific reason for wanting a term for the voice, could you give us some context?  Otherwise, I'm afraid the answer might have to be “There isn't one…”

First sentence of the article: "Monotimbral ... is usually used in reference to electronic synthesizers." So, no, it's not a term to use outside that context. It's like asking whether the human voice has two manuals, or is touch-sensitive. Sachs-Hornbostel is the best system for classifying instruments, but it doesn't concern itself with polyphony. Maybe there's a better term for what you're thinking of, but the article makes it clear that within the synthesizer context, "timbre" means essentially "patch," while even "polyphonic" has a specific practical meaning about pressing keys.

Maybe you'd like to edit to make more clear the meanings that you're looking for, and asking whether there's a better universal terminology. E.g. a flute can vary its timbre (breathier, more focused, overblowing), but aside from extended techniques, is usually monophonic, while I guess a kazoo would be an example with little timbral range?

@AndyBonner I guess the issue is that I don’t really consider say, a guitar as having multiple timbres. I mean, sure it can make other sounds but we typically use it for its specific sound that it makes when pluck a string right? So, I only really consider the voice as having multi timbres or a synthesizer. But the voice is monophonic, and a synth can be polyphonic so that’s where my confusion is coming from with the terminology and definitions.

I return to my comment above about "manuals" or "touch-sensitive." The word "timbre" has a meaning outside of discussions of the specs of synths, as does the word "polyphony," and the problem is that we're trying to pull those definitions into and out of a context. The long and the short is that "multitimbral" is a word used when comparing the specs of synths, and isn't useful to a broader discussion. (Also: for more on the timbral range of a guitar, try plucking at the bridge, over the neck, with and without a pick, with the fleshy part of the finger, using harmonics, muting the strings...)

"A synth can be polyphonic": The best definition of "polyphonic" outside of shopping synths is a definition about the structure and approach of composition. "Polyphony" is a concept, and the synth world has borrowed it to describe a feature. Also: I'm surprised this conversation hasn't veered toward Tuvan throat-singing yet!

Multitimbrality relates to layering multiple timbres, at the same time. Very many instruments, both monotimbral synths and acoustic instruments, can produce multiple timbres, but only one at a time. I don't believe there is a separate classification for them.
In fact, I'm having trouble to search for examples of an instrument that could not produce multiple timbres. Perhaps some first electronic generators, producing raw sine waves?

I'd say piano is very close to monotimbral

@ojs timbre of a piano note changes with its volume (though one cannot control these two parameters independently). Moreover, pianos typically have soft pedal, which also changes the timbre.

This is why I wrote "very close"

@ojs alright, no point to argue about that. The point I'm making is that I don't believe there is a classification of instruments based on their timbral range. We rather say that some of them have access to broader range of timbres.
